# Get ObjectContext from DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a DbContext application where I need to use ObjectContext on a certain form (data binding issue with DbContext). I tried accessing the ObjectContext entities using

```
var oc = ((IObjectContextAdapter)MyEntities).ObjectContext;
```

but entities do not show up when typing `oc.Students`. What shall I do to have access to entities?

Comment: That is because the type returned is `ObjectContext` which has no knowledge of the `Students` table.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. And how may I query the 'Students' table with the resulting ObjectContext?

Comment: I don't think you can without casting it back to your DbContext class which holds the DbSet definitions. Perhaps you should just expose the DbContext, and then cast it to the ObjectContext if you need it in other places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the method `CreateObjectSet<TEntity>()`

In your scenario, that would be used like so

```cs
var oc = ((IObjectContextAdapter)MyEntities).ObjectContext;
var query = oc.CreateObjectSet<Student>();
```

You can then use LINQ to build your `query` much the same way you would with an `IQueryable<Student>`

Comment: Thanks. Although I do not need this any more (I sorted out the DbContext binding) I still accept your answer as it works nicely.